# Increase modal width of lightning quick action aura with child lwc

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, modal

I have a lightning quick action using aura with lwc as child component.

```
 <aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:html tag="style">
        .cuf-content {
        padding: 0 0rem !important;
        }
        .slds-p-around--medium {
        padding: 0rem !important;
        }
        .slds-modal__content{
        overflow-y:hidden !important;
        height:unset !important;
        max-height:unset !important;     
        }
    </aura:html>
  
   <c:customLeadConversion recordId="{!v.recordId}"/> 
    
</aura:component>
```

Child LWC HTML:

```
<template>
    <header class="slds-modal__header">
        <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-modal__title slds-hyphenate">Convert Lead</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
            
        </div>
        <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
        <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" onclick={cancel}>Cancel</button>
        <button class="slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick={save}>
          Convert
        </button>
        </footer>
</template>
```

Can anyone here help me how to increase the width of the modal? TIA

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This usually works for me

<aura:html tag="style">
.slds-modal__container {
min-width: 90vw;
}
</aura:html>

Comment: you freaking lifesaver! was following this stupid workaround article which was so convoluted and didn't help me close the LWC modal https://www.santanuatonline.com/how-to-increase-the-width-of-quick-action-and-call-the-lwc-from-quick-action/